# Oracle Business Intelligence 10 data source

Tags: obiee

I am new to Oracle Business Intelligence (10). Can it connect to a data source (Oracle) and use PL SQL script or procedure/function, etc to generate a report? Where can I find some tutorial/documentation on that? Thanks.

I am not sure the product I use is OBIEE or not. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new analysis using the Direct Database Request option described [here](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/direct_database_request).

The example below was taken from [this link](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/direct_database_request_table_function)

**Create the function in the database:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_row AS OBJECT (my_num NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_tab AS TABLE OF my_row;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_table_function RETURN my_tab
PIPELINED IS
BEGIN
PIPE ROW(my_row(1.23));
END;
/
```

**Create the direct SQL request:**

```
SELECT CAST(my_num AS double precision) AS my_num3 FROM TABLE(my_table_function)
```

However, you need special privileges to do this. In 11g the required privileges are:

- [Presentation catalog privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10543/mgrgrpsusers.htm#BIESC191):

  - Edit Direct Database Analysis
  - Execute Direct Database Analysis
- [RPD privileges](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10543/intro.htm#CJHGABJI):

  - [Execute direct database request](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/dataaccess.htm#CHDJFFEG)

I think the same privileges apply for 10g, contact your Bi Admin =)

Comment: Thanks. I have arrived at the same solution of direct database access. Although I need administrator privileges. Now I am working with other people on that. Lot to learn.